# Grafana: How to avoid executing query while zoom in or out?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

I have 4 timeseries panels in my dashboard and the query does not have any timefilter in it. So, all the data is fetched.

Now, when ever I zoom in or out, these queries are re-executed. Since, they are going to fetch same results, there is no use in executing them again. How can I disable this re-execution?

Comment: Same issue or question for me. It makes zooming in very slow. I suspect that this is a weakness of Grafana. That is, it's just how it works. I have an idea of doing the query in a table and then time filtering with a transformation in a graph. I get the impression that Grafana does not have a local (to a panel) time range and it will re-run the table query anyway.